# How can I get the value of an item from firebase using uid?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase realtime DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef7Et.png)

I pass the id of the item to the next activity. I would like to use the id to retrieve the name of the category and set it to a string. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so  far?

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categories").child("pass your id")
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In onDataChange you can receive the value.